# how to implement an atomic counter in aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, mutex, amazon-elasticache

I need to implement a kind of ticket system in aws, using only serverless technologies.  The functionality needs to be sort of like the number system at the post office:  you take a ticket, which has a number on it.  As the requestor, you know your number.  The roll shifts, and the next customer gets a number that is incremented by one.  This ticket will be requested by handlers in a lambda function, which could be getting called in parallel. I know this sounds like a global lock, and it is, but that's the requirement - please don't tell me to redesign my use-case so it's not necessary.

Nonfunctional requirements:

- should be globally consistent
- should be performant, ie. hundreds or, ideally, thousands of requests per second would be possible
- consistent: no duplicate numbers
- failures are ok, and retry is ok, as long as consistency is maintained.

What I've tried:

- Dynamodb:  I implemented a distributed lock using the go sdk and this `"cirello.io/dynamolock"` package.  it works but the lock/unlock cycle takes 700ms - its too slow.
- Also Dynamodb:  I used `UpdateExpression` and `ReturnValues`  in `an UpdateItem` call, but it's still only like 125/second from within the datacenter.
- elasticache.  Couldn't get it working because the complexity of setting up a VPC to connect the lambda, and then losing connectivity to dynamodb.  I hear you can get around this with a NAT Gateway, but by that time, your serverless framework app starts looking pretty ridiculously complex for a counter.

Comment: Just a note regarding the VPC connectivity: You only need a dynamodb vpc endpoint: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/vpc-endpoints-dynamodb.html. No need to set up a NAT gateway.

Answer (score 1):

DynamoDB supports a maximum of 1000 writes per second to a single partition. If this is acceptable performance, the correct DynamoDB call is:

```js
dynamoDB.update({
  TableName: "my-atomic-counter-db",
  Key: "my-ticket-counter",
  ReturnValues: "UPDATED_NEW",
  UpdateExpression: `SET #value = if_not_exists(#value, :start) + :increment`,
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ':start': 0,
    ':increment': 1,
  },
  ExpressionAttributeNames: {
    '#value': 'value',
  },
```

If you need to support more than 1000 tickets per second, you can increase the 'increment' counter to a higher number, and answer 'ticket requests' as a batch. For example, send ticket requests through SQS, read messages in batches of 10, call dynamoDB with an increment value of 10, read the return value of the highest ticket, and hand out tickets from T...T-10.

Comment: This is what I did in the second bullet point above.  To be fair, the performance is better than 7 per second - I manage to get about 100 new tickets in ~800 ms.  But it's still surprisingly slow.

Comment: the SQS idea is interesting though - ill give it a go, and if it works, accept this an the answer.